# How to manage props of a list of components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, jsx, react-state-management

I am trying to create an ObjectList component, which would contain a list of Children.

```
const MyList = ({childObjects}) => {
    [objects, setObjects] = useState(childObjects)

    ...

    return (
        <div>
            {childObjects.map((obj, idx) => (
                <ListChild
                    obj={obj}
                    key={idx}
                    collapsed={false}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyList
```

Each Child has a `collapsed` property, which toggles its visibility. I am trying to have a **Collapse All** button on a parent level which will toggle the collapsed property of all of its children. However, it must only change their prop once, without binding them all to the same state. I was thinking of having a list of `ref`s, one for each child and to enumerate over it, but not sure if it is a sound idea from design perspective.

How can I reference a dynamic list of child components and manage their state?

Alternatively, is there a better approach to my problem?

Comment: note: _don't use array index as key_, the whole point of the key attribute is for React to know what happened, and should identify _the thing_ you're building, not _the list position_ that thing happens to have right now. Use something in `obj` that uniquely identifies each element instead. React checks that value to see if it needs to completely rebuild something, or just "move it around in the DOM". If you use array elements and then things get rearranged, React can't do that super fast "just move the elements around" and will instead waste a ton of time completely rewriting the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am new to react, probably there is a better way, but the code below does what you explained, I used only 1 state to control all the objects and another state to control if all are collapsed.

**Index.jsx**

```
import MyList from "./MyList";

function Index() {
  const objList = [
    { data: "Obj 1", id: 1, collapsed: false },
    { data: "Obj 2", id: 2, collapsed: false },
    { data: "Obj 3", id: 3, collapsed: false },
    { data: "Obj 4", id: 4, collapsed: false },
    { data: "Obj 5", id: 5, collapsed: false },
    { data: "Obj 6", id: 6, collapsed: false },
  ];

  return <MyList childObjects={objList}></MyList>;
}

export default Index;
```

**MyList.jsx**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ListChild from "./ListChild";

const MyList = ({ childObjects }) => {
  const [objects, setObjects] = useState(childObjects);
  const [allCollapsed, setallCollapsed] = useState(false);

  const handleCollapseAll = () => {
    allCollapsed = !allCollapsed;

    for (const obj of objects) {
      obj.collapsed = allCollapsed;
    }
    setallCollapsed(allCollapsed);
    setObjects([...objects]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleCollapseAll}>Collapse All</button>

      <br />
      <br />

      {objects.map((obj) => {
        return (
          <ListChild
            obj={obj.data}
            id={obj.id}
            key={obj.id}
            collapsed={obj.collapsed}
            state={objects}
            setState={setObjects}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyList;
```

**ListChild.jsx**

```
function ListChild(props) {
  const { obj, id, collapsed, state, setState } = props;

  const handleCollapse = (id) => {
    console.log("ID", id);

    for (const obj of state) {
      if (obj.id == id) {
        obj.collapsed = !obj.collapsed;
      }
    }
    setState([...state]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {obj} {collapsed ? "COLLAPSED!" : ""}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          handleCollapse(id);
        }}
      >
        Collapse This
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ListChild;
```